# C++: Identifier of class name in same namepace undefined

Tags: c++

I have two classes `SHCalculator` and `SphericalLightProbe` in separate files. I completely stripped them down to present the error I'm getting so these are the four files:

**SHCalculator.h**

```
#pragma once
namespace SphericalHarmonics
{
    class SHCalculator
    {
    private:

    public:
        void Test();
        SphericalLightProbe Test2();
    };
}
```

**SHCalculator.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"

#include "SphericalLightProbe.h"
#include "SHCalculator.h"    

namespace SphericalHarmonics
{

    void SHCalculator::Test()
    {
        SphericalLightProbe sp(2, 3.4f);

        for (int i = 0; i < sp.coeffs.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << sp.coeffs[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    SphericalLightProbe SHCalculator::Test2()
    {
        SphericalLightProbe sp(2, 4.3f);

        for (int i = 0; i < sp.coeffs.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << sp.coeffs[i] << std::endl;
        }
        return sp;
    }
}
```

**SphericalLightProbe.h**

```
#pragma once

namespace SphericalHarmonics
{
    class SphericalLightProbe
    {
    private:

    public:

        SphericalLightProbe() { }
        SphericalLightProbe(int numCoeffs);
        SphericalLightProbe(int numCoeffs, float value);

        std::vector<Eigen::Vector3f> coeffs;

    };
}
```

**SphericalLightProbe.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "SphericalLightProbe.h"

namespace SphericalHarmonics
{

    SphericalLightProbe::SphericalLightProbe(int numCoeffs)
    {
        coeffs.resize(numCoeffs);
    }

    SphericalLightProbe::SphericalLightProbe(int numCoeffs, float value)
    {
        coeffs.resize(numCoeffs, Eigen::Vector3f(value, value, value));
    }
}
```

This gives me a bunch of errors:

```
C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
C2059   syntax error: '('
Message     see declaration of 'SphericalHarmonics::SHCalculator'   
E0020   identifier "SphericalLightProbe" is undefined   
C3646   'Test2': unknown override specifier 
C2039   'Test2': is not a member of 'SphericalHarmonics::SHCalculator'
```

If I remove `Test2()` by commenting it out, all errors disappear. I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: Does `SHCalculator.h` `#include "SphericalLightProbe.h"`?

Comment: @molbdnilo nope, these are already in the precompiled header. See the answer below.

Comment: @RolandDeschain Sometimes we are forced to avoid any 3rd-party-library includes in our headers (to prevent conflicts), but our own headers should be included where required (as long as we prevent conflicts, which you seem to do safely using namespace).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the includes in your `SHCalculator.h` header;
Try something like:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "SphericalLightProbe.h"

namespace SphericalHarmonics
{
    class SHCalculator
    {
    private:

    public:
        void Test();
        SphericalLightProbe Test2();
    };
}
```

> **Note** that if your `SHCalculator.cpp` file includes above, the duplicate `#include "SphericalLightProbe.h"` line is not required.

But if you want to avoid for whatever reason the include, use forward declaration instead, like:

```
#pragma once

namespace SphericalHarmonics {

class SphericalLightProbe;

// ...

} // namespace SphericalHarmonics
```

> **Note** that forward declaration *normally* does not force you to switch to pointers (like `SphericalLightProbe *`).

Comment: Could avoid the include by using a forward declaration.

Comment: OK, now I'm confused: 1. I read one should avoid includes in the header files. 2. including is just a simple copy-paste operation done in the compiler, right? I have already included `SphericalLightProbe.h` in `SHCalculator.cpp`. At at this point, what to include where and when seems just arbitrary to me...

Comment: Oh, btw yes this answer fixed the issue, will mark as soon as it lets me :)

Comment: you should avoid *unnecessary* includes in a header file. Symbols must be declared before use though, and if you need to use a symbol then you need to have a declaration in scope.

Comment: @RolandDeschain My rule of thumb, and it is pretty widely used, is that each file should include all the files that contain the types and functions that it is using.  In this case, `SHCalculator.h` has the type `SphericalLightProbe` used in it, so it must include the file that defines that type.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you. I'll try and go by that rule as well to avoid errors as this in the future.

Comment: @NathanOliver You can forward declare without changing to a pointer for the `Test2` function.